# How do I use the forvo API with jquery ajax?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, api

I am trying this:

```
   $("i.icon-play-circle").click(function(){
        var word = "你好";
        var url = 'http://apifree.forvo.com/key/XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX/format/json/action/standard-pronunciation/word/'+encodeURI(word)+'/language/zh';
        $.ajax({
            url: url,
            crossDomain: true,
            dataType: "jsonp",
            success: function (i,item) {
                alert(item);
            },
            error: function () {
                alert('foo');
            }
        });
    });
```

I got this error in the firebug console:

```
SyntaxError: invalid label
[Break On This Error]   

{"items":[{"id":1967282,"addtime":"2013-01-21 23:35:31","hits

zh?cal...0549189 (line 1, col 1)
```

**UPDATE:**

Here is how the url should be formatted if you want to get back a jsonp:

apifree.forvo.com/key/XXXXXXX/format/json/**callback/your_function_here**/action/standard-pronunciation/word/你好/language/zh

**result:**

`pronounce({"items":[{"id":436,"addtime":"2008-03-16 10:40:22","hits":4346,"username":"geneboy","sex":"m","country":"China","code":"zh","langname":"Mandarin Chinese","pathmp3":"http:\/\/apifree.forvo.com\/audio\/2i253j1l2e2m1b2i2f3q2d2g2f341k2q1f3h2g1b3m223i342b2q3k28323n2732372e1b1o393k2k1m1i2q3m353q253l36371l3k3a3q3d271h3133342o263g3223_3m2d2p2f2d1f2k3n1h3i3g2q263f293e1b253g1i2f2h1t1t","pathogg":"http:\/\/apifree.forvo.com\/audio\/3b2625373d3f2n1j233d2b211i3j3p3g1b1j1m312i3j2f261l2e2n383k371i1m3a3l292o3k2h29293h3q3c3f362h2k2h271m3i312o211h3m3g1h3e351m2n2d27_293q2c2l1m343a2q26343a391k1p3m1o2a2q333f35371t1t","rate":5,"num_votes":5,"num_positive_votes":5}]})`

**I now need help writing a function that prints the "pathmp3" value.**

Comment: That doesn't look like a jsonp url to me.

Comment: According to the last line of the error it appears that jquery has added `?callback=?` to the url automatically. I added it manually just to be sure and I got the same error. Is that what you meant by your statement?

Comment: @webmagnets are you sure that that website uses `callback` as the name of the callback as opposed to something else?

Comment: `http://api.forvo.com/documentation/standard-pronunciation/` says: ```format. Values:
    xml
    json (for jsonp, use param: callback/function_name)
    js-tag (returns a script tag for the pronunciation)```. How should I interpret that?

Comment: @webmagnets I'm not sure what they mean by `use param`.  Is that something like `callback/your_function_name_here` or are they saying use `?callback=?` OR `?function_name=?`.  Try the first one I guess

Comment: I have no idea what I should put for "your_function_name_here". Any ideas?

Comment: Anybody else have any ideas on this?

Comment: so everyone can see your api key just by viewing source code...

Comment: I used a free throwaway api key in the jsfiddle. No one can see the key elsewhere.

Comment: No, I mean, using url (with the key) in jQuery makes it visible by everyone those who view source code.

Comment: Ah! I see. How can I fix that? I am using Rails and Heroku.

Comment: You must do this inside action controller and just render mp3 url in html to play audio

Comment: The mp3 url is only available for 2 hours once it is generated and the license agreement says that I can't save the mp3s. Therefore, I think I need to do this in jquery. Am I still thinking wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the ajax code that worked for me:

```
    word = "你好"
    var url = 'http://apifree.forvo.com/key/XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX/format/json/callback/pronounce/action/standard-pronunciation/word/'+encodeURI(word)+'/language/zh';
    $.ajax({
        url: url,
        jsonpCallback: "pronounce",
        dataType: "jsonp",
        type: "jsonp",
        success: function (json) {
       var mp3 = json.items[0].pathmp3;
       var ogg = json.items[0].pathogg;
   },
    error: function(){
        console.log("error");
}});
```